# Google map showing only states of USA and shows only cities of corresponding state when clicked along with zoom

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

Peace be upon you all

I have a simple question. I want to embed a **Google map** in my website in which it **only shows USA map** without allowing users to zoom out from USA map to somewhere else. Most importantly i want it to show **only names of states** with default view and display **only corresponding names of cities**  by zooming when clicking on particular state not anything else.

So is there a way to do that or i have to look for some other services?? Any idea, suggestion or help will be appreciated.

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
<script>
function initialize() {
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(39.574912, -102.344687);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 4,
    maxZoom: 7,
    center: myLatlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>

    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

Comment: see this anwser http://stackoverflow.com/a/19999036/142904 and this  https://support.google.com/earth/answer/148130?hl=en

Comment: Show your Code please.

Comment: Hey i have edited the question and put the code. I know about maxzoom and zoom in map options but i want it to be what i mentioned in my question..is it possible with google maps?

Comment: @KristianDamian in the link you have given is only showing some region mentioned in code with their popularity values. i want it to zoom as we click on it and get corresponding cities...by the way i was not expecting -2 from someone